How to get this output in TABLE format
I want to get the below command output in table format using Linux commands:
aws --region us-east-1 cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=ConsoleLogin --start-time $START_TIME | \
jq -r .Events[].CloudTrailEvent | \
jq '.userIdentity.arn, .eventTime, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin')

Current output:
"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"

"2024-11-29T06:48:05Z"

"Success"

"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"

"2024-11-29T03:12:14Z"

"Success"

"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"

"2024-11-29T02:42:48Z"

"Success"


Can you please [edit] the question to include some additional details: Firstly, what exactly does the "table format" need to look like? Include a sample of the desired output as well as the current output. Secondly, this is probably really a question about formatting data, not the AWS API, so it would be useful to include a sample of the raw input (i.e. what comes directly from the AWS command if you don't add jq on the end at all). That way people who know about jq (or other tools) can help you without needing an AWS account to generate sample data for themselves.

This is for monitoring the console login events. We want this data either in csv format or table format to send out an email notification from the pipeline job.

Desired output:"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com | "2024-11-29T06:48:05Z" | "Success"
"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"| "2024-11-29T03:12:14Z" | "Success"
"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"| "2024-11-29T02:42:48Z" | "Success"

"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com | "2024-11-29T06:48:05Z" | "Success"
"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"| "2024-11-29T03:12:14Z" | "Success"
"arn:aws:sts::accountnum:assumed-role/role/user@com"| "2024-11-29T02:42:48Z" | "Success"

Please click the "edit" button under the question, and add all the necessary details in directly - including both the input and output examples. There's no need to mark which parts are new, the system tracks history, just make it as helpful as you can for someone who comes to the question for the first time.

For CSV output, change your second jq invocation to:
jq ‘ [.userIdentity.arn, .eventTime, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin]
| @csv'

You might want to combine the two invocations into one, and/or use @tsv or join("|") instead of @csv.
The Linux/Unix column command might be relevant here as well.

Thanks for the answer. I am getting this error while executing this command.            aws --region us-east-1 cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=ConsoleLogin --start-time 2024-11-29 > console.json
jq -r '.Events[].CloudTrailEvent | [.userIdentity.arn, .eventTime, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin] | @csv' console.json        jq: error (at console.json:103): Cannot index string with string "userIdentity"

I am not able to send the full json content. Its not allowing

First have cloudtrail command, followed by jq command and first command works fine, and jq command throws below error                                                                    jq: error (at console.json:103): Cannot index string with string "userIdentity"

The two jq commands would have to be combined carefully.

Thanks everyone. Its working fine now. Issue with jq combination as highlighted.

aws --region us-east-1 cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=ConsoleLogin --start-time $START_TIME | jq -r '.Events[].CloudTrailEvent' | jq '[.userIdentity.arn, .eventTime, .responseElements.ConsoleLogin] | @csv')
